# Why is there a difference in offset between ida and gdb?

Tags: ida, gdb

A PIE binary, when loaded in IDA shows an offset (`0x202010`) different from gdb (`0x2013a1`) for instruction located at `0x555555554c68` in (gdb) and `0xc68` (in IDA). How can I explain this discrepancy?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "Position Independent Executable" binaries, the loader is free to relocate the binary using some base address. In the case of GDB, the binary is mapped already into memory, the offset `0x2013a1` in the memory operand is *calculated relatively with the current `RIP`* (which is the address of the next instruction). The current instruction size is `0x6f - 0x68 = 0x7` bytes, so in considering with the address of the current instruction, we have an offset:

```
0x2013a1 + 0x7 = 0x2013a8
```

In the case of `IDA`, you see the "static" virtual address, the offset `0x202010` in the memory operand is *calculated relatively with the base address of the code segment*, so in considering with the address of the current instruction, we have an offset:

```
0x202010 - 0xc68 = 0x2013a8
```

These values are coherent for both cases.

Comment: The offset, which is rip relative, should be the same irrespective of the base address.

Comment: In the case of IDA, the offset `0x20210` of the memory operand and the offset `0xc68` of the instruction are counted from the same base address of the code segment. This is different from the case of DBG, the number `0x2013a1` is relative with the current `RIP`. I give more detail in the answer.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now. I didn't understand that IDA calculates the offset *relative to the base address of the code segment*.

Answer (score 1):

IDA shows a simplified operand, with the `rip+<delta>` value resolved, so you don't have to calculate it yourself. If you prefer, you can view the original form of rip-relative instructions by enabling "explicit RIP addressing" in processor-specific options.

Comment: `IDA shows a simplified operand, with the rip+<delta> value resolved` - and this value is relative to the base of the code segment. Right?

Comment: And thanks for `explicit RIP addressing`, I didn't know about that.